# Make any class reference counted with inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

In my new project I wish to (mostly for to see how it will work out) completely ban raw pointers from my code.

My first approach was to let all classes inherit from this simple class:
    template 
    class Base
    {
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr ptr;
    };

And simple use class::ptr wherever I need a pointer.

This approach seemed suitable until I realized sometimes my objects wish to pass the 'this' pointer to other objects. Letting my objects just wrap it inside a shared_ptr won't do since then there could be two owners for the same pointer. I assume this is bad.

My next idea was to change the 'Base' class to implement reference counting itself, thus every instance of classes that inherits from 'Base' can only have one count.

Is this a good solution, are there any better and can boost and/or stl already solve this problem for me?

Comment: Why do you want to "completely ban raw pointers"? Are you trying to avoid making design decisions about object ownership?

Comment: In some cases yes, my project is a game where objects may not have a clear owner (i.e an enemy spawns another enemy then dies. But it's also much of an experiment, how far can you take the concept. Then there is also the laziness of never having to think about memory management! ;)

Comment: @Charles I actually think it's a pretty good idea if we rephrase it slightly differently, having very strict RAII compliance. However, I would rephrase it to, "completely ban raw pointers for memory management." It would be very difficult to avoid passing 'raw' pointers around completely, but one could, with a firm policy and starting a new codebase, build everything using just scoped_ptr and scoped_array. Those already form the RAII-compliant primitives to store the results of operator new/new[] over 'raw' pointers.

Comment: @Charles ... or perhaps better stated, "completely ban any cases where explicit calls to delete/delete[] are required", even in the implementation of a class.We can still effectively do anything with scoped_ptr and scoped_array as our memory management primitives instead of pointers. The only case where explicit memory deallocation is unavoidable is if one wishes to implement a memory allocator or implement a data structure that uses one.

Comment: @stinky472: I think it's a good policy to avoid ever having to manually use `delete` or `delete[]` but that's not what the question asks. Surely choosing when and where to have shared ownership is a necessary part of the design process; banning all uses of raw pointers is neither a substitute for this nor practical in many projects.

Comment: Only one reference count ? Well, it depends, if you have a diamond inheritance, then you may have several instances of `Base` in the object, and thus several different counts.

Comment: @Charles agreed. Also I think the OP needs to be aware that applying reference-counting uniformly has its share of headaches (circular referencing, object lifetimes being prolonged far longer than they should just because some class A stores a strong reference to B, etc). I work in such a system unfortunately and while the reference-counting is useful for dealing with shared resources across threads, doing it for everything is a true PITA.

Comment: @Matthieu: I think I worded that wrong, what I meant was that if there were two owners to a single object then two different ref counts would apply to the object.

@stinky472: You're probably right, and as I said before, this is more of a test to see how far you can take it. Since the api I'm working with is in C I've already had to make exceptions.

Comment: @monoceres if you proceed with that approach, be careful about storing persistent strong references. Favor weak references (weak_ptr) when you can for persistent storage in anything but a single 'owner' unless multiple are really necessary, and you'll avoid a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).

On another note, when using `shared_ptr`, you need to be aware of the possibility of circular references. To avoid this, you can use [`weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm). This means you will need some way to distinguish between the two of them, so simply having a typedef `class::ptr` may not suffice.

Comment: Just what I wanted! I had a feeling boost already had the answer.

I guess another typedef to weak_ptr will solve that problem.